# Почему не получается добавить зависимости и происходит ошибка "Dependency 'org.telegram:telegrambots:6.5.0' not found"?

Tags: java, maven, зависимости, telegrambots, version

Пытаюсь добавить зависимость из `maven repository`. Пытался добавить через `File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries`, там не находит. Причём maven мне предлагает только две версии:

[image: две версии, которые мне предлагает maven]

Comment: Попробовал добавить mvnrepository
'<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>mvnrepository</id>
   <url>https://mvnrepository.com</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>'

Answer (score 0):

У вас указан неправильный `artifactId`, вот [правильные](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots#usage) координаты зависимости:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Указывать репозиторий Maven Central необязательно, он используется по-умолчанию.

Comment: Изменил, не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Помогло переустановка Intellij Idea, скорее всего были сбиты настройки maven'а